# Django Apache serve downloadable images

Tags: django, apache, download

I have a webservices application written in django to which the communication is through andriod app. I have an API call which uploads the images to a media url specified in settings. I have to serve the uploaded files as publicly downloadable files as they will be accessed by the andriod app through API call. This is the reason why I cannot use forms as [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/) explains. I am using apache to serve my django application through mod_wsgi.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: You should explain why you think the need to serve them as downloadable files means you can't upload them via forms, as those things have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: The android app creates a form with post method and makes an API call to the application url. Because this form is created externally and it won't contain the django's csrf_token, I cannot validate this as a form. It will flag the form as invalid if I tried to validate the form in the process of uploading. Now the new API call to access the image will also be similar. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: None of this follows. You can mark your form as csrf_exempt, or get the token from the cookie as described in the [section on Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax). But that still has nothing to do with how you would *serve* the file for download anyway, and I can't understand how you're making that association.